# Autocomplete in multiple text boxes using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a requirement where I have to implement autocomplete feature using AngularJS.

Something like [this](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete).

The above is good for autocomplete on one text box.
But I am looking to implement autocomplete on more than one text box where the number of options in the second box will depend on the value selected in the first box.

For example, Let us say that there are two search boxes. The first box can have state names as input (New York, Michigan, etc). Depending on which state is selected, the second searchbox should only display the cities in that state.

Can someone point me to any resources/tutorial/examples which can help me implement a solution for this scenario.

Comment: Just change the values bound to the second autocomplete box as the first one is updated.

Answer (score 1):

I think this 
    [ng-Autocomplete][1]
will be the best solution for this kind of problem. Off course building one like this is appreciable.

```
[1]: http://plnkr.co/edit/GF3nM3XfYX9El2w11pGo?p=preview
```